# Changing the order of integration in triple integral

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

Will you please help me change the order of integration in the following?

1. $\int_{0}^{1}dx \int_{0}^{1}dy \int_{0}^{x^2+y^2} f dz$ . we need:
   $\int_{?}^{?}dz \int_{?}^{?}dy \int_{?}^{?} f dx$
2. $\int_{0}^{1}dx \int_{0}^{1-x}dy \int_{0}^{x+y} f dz$ . we need:
   $\int_{?}^{?}dz \int_{?}^{?}dx \int_{?}^{?} f dy$

As for the first one, $\int_{0}^{1}dz \int_{0}^{\sqrt{z}}dy \int_{0}^{\sqrt{z-y^2} } f dx$?

As for the second one- I have no idea how to do it ... Will you help ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first one is right. For the second one: We have $0 \le x \le 1$, $0 \le y \le 1-x$ and $0 \le z \le x+y$, so the largest value $z$ can attain is $1$, as 
$$ z \le x+y \le x+(1-x) = 1 $$
Given $z$, we have $x\le x+y = z$, so $0 \le x \le z$, and finally for $y$, we must fulfill $y \ge 0$, $y \le 1-x$, and $x+y\le z\iff y \le z-x$. That gives (note that $z \le 1$, hence $y\le z-x$ implies $y \le 1-x$) 
$$ \int_0^1 \int_0^{1-x} \int_0^{x+y} f\; dz\,dy\,dx 
  = \int_0^1 \int_0^{z} \int_0^{z-x} f\; dy\,dx\, dz $$

Comment: thanks a lot @martini! you have been very helpful so far !

Comment: I can't understand why $0\leq x \leq z$ ... I understand that $x\leq x+y $ ... But we don't always have $x+y=z$ ... So how did you deduce that $x+y=z$ ? Thanks !